# How to find newly added/modified nodes/relationship between two date-time

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, date-range, auditing

How does on find newly added nodes in Neo4j database between to two timestamps (date + time)?
E.g., I need to find out newly created nodes/relationships between yesterday and today.

I also need basically the same for modified nodes/relationship between yesterday and today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [auditing support of Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing), which is [supported by Spring Data Neo4j starting with version 5.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.5-0-0), to fill attributes with the appropriate values and then use the normal query facilities to query the required range.

Comment: Spring Audit support will not capture if database records are manipulated directly..so it won't capture those changes.

Comment: So what is your actual question? How to make the timestamps available? Or how to do a simple between query?

Comment: -how to do a simple between the query

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried? Why doesn't the stuff described in the reference documentation and in tutorials doesn't work for you?